# Scheduling Calendar?

Tags: forms, calendar

I am trying to create a form that has pay-pal integration as well as a scheduling calendar. The calendar is what is really tripping me up. I want the user to select the date, and then a time, - but I only want certain days/times to be available, somewhat like a airline reservation calendar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/imike/edit to block certain dates in jQuery datepicker. For more information I think more details are needed (as what server side scripting you want to use and how is the data stored)